# Can't get bootstrap modal show on submit

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I tried using the following code to show a modal pop up after the user enter data and click on a button on existing modal pop up.  Can anyone point out what I did wrong.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aguafina+Script">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
       <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.2.8/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddPkgPrompt"><i class="fa fa-cube fa-4x"></i><h2>Add Package</h2></a>
<div class="modal fade" id="AddPkgPrompt" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AddPkgPromptLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h2 class="modal-title text-center" id="AddPkgPromptLabel">Add Package</h2>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="frmAddPkg">
             <div class="modal-body"> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="opnshp">
                                <input type="radio" id="1" name="rbshp" value="1" required /><label>1</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="2" name="rbshp" value="2" required /><label>2</label>
                   </div>
                     </div>
       </div>
                </div>              
             <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                     <button name="btnAddPkg" id="btnAddPkg" type="submit" class="clsAddPkg btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp;Create</button>
              </div>
             </div>
            </form>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="RrsultModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ResultModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h2 class="modal-title text-center" id="ResultModal">xx</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="ct_schpkgresult"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$("#frmAddPkg").submit(function(e) {
  var shpid = get_radio_value();
  var dataString = '&shpid=' + shpid; 
   $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "t2.php",
             data: dataString,
    async: false,
             cache: false,
             success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
      $('#LookupModal').modal('show'); /*TMP*/
     /*$('#AddPkgPrompt').modal('hide');*/
     /*window.location.replace("index.php");*/
             },
             error: function(err) {
              console.log(err);
             }
      });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

User selects one of the radio buttons on existing form "frmAddPkg" and click on a button which triggers ajax call to t2.php.  The t2.php does it job correctly.  I just want to add the line `$('#ResultModal').modal('show')` to display the result but nothing shown after existing modal vanished.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

Comment: As reminded, I extracted all related code.

Comment: Did you try **attaching the event when the DOM is ready**?? `$(document).ready(function() { /* declare everything here */  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe add e.preventDefault(); to avoid the form being submitted by the default form action?

```
$("#frmAddPkg").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your modal like

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="getCodeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" id="getCodeClose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

but never forget to call jquery and bootstrap scripts plugins.
            Msssage

```
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and on ajax success

```
           success: function(msg) {
                $("#getCode").html(msg);
                $('#getCodeModal').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false
                  });
                $("#getCodeModal").modal('show');
            }
```